# Proving that $\min\{d(p,q),1\}$ is a metric space.

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove or disprove that $\min\{d(p,q),1\}$ is a metric space, and I am having a problem proving or disproving the triangular inequality proposition for the metric space.

Currently I am trying to tackle this by proof by cases and if $d(p,q) \leq 1$ then the triangular inequality works. But for $d(p,q) >1$, I am having problem showing that $d(p,q) \leq  \min\{d(p,r),1\} + \{d(r,q),1\}$

Comment: What does $\min\{d(p,r),1\}+\{d(r,q),1\}$ mean? Don't you mean $\min\{d(p,r),1\}+\min\{d(r,q),1\}$?

Comment: By $d(p,q)\le$ did you mean $\min\{d(p,q),1\}\le$ ?

Answer (score 2):

$d(p,r)\leq d(p,q)+d(q,r)$.

Suppose that $d(p,r)>1, \min(d(p,r),1)=1$,

if $d(p,q)<1, d(q,r)<1, \min(d(p,q),1)=d(p,q), \min(d(p,r),1)=d(p,r)$ implies that $\min(d(p,q),1)+\min(d(q,r),1)=d(p,q)+d(q,r)\geq d(p,r)\geq 1$.

if $d(p,q)$ or $d(q,r)\geq 1, \min(d(p,q),1)+\min(d(q,r),1)\geq 1$.

Suppose $d(p,r)\leq 1$, $\min(d(p,r),1)=d(p,r)$

if $d(p,q)<1, d(q,r)<1, \min(d(p,q),1)+\min(d(q,r),1)=d(p,q)+d(q,r)\geq d(p,r)$.

If $d(p,q)$ or $d(q,r)\geq 1$, $\min(d(p,q),1)+\min(d(q,r),1)geq 1\geq d(p,r)$.